# AltBeacon Android Beacon Library, RegionBootstrap beaconManager.onbind

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I have a Service which implements `BeaconConsumer` and `BootstrapNotifier`. In this case I need to call  `beaconManager.bind(this);` to bind BeaconManager in `startBeaconManager` method. But also I use RegionBootstrap to range beacons. As RegionBootstrap includes    `beaconManager.bind(beaconConsumer);`, it causes not to start ranging any beacons. Note that I have also `stopBeaconManager` method to unbind BeaconManager.

Do you have any suggestion to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Understand that `RegionBootstrap` is just a convenience class for setting up monitoring that makes it easier to set up background detections when combined with an `Application` class.  If you are creating your own Service instance that is a `BeaconConsumer` and launching the service on app startup automatically, there probably is no reason to use `RegionBootstrap`.

Just do the `bind` call in the service's `onCreate` method, and start monitoring when you get the call to `onBeaconServiceConnected`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to use `RegionBootstrap` for sending push notification to user in case of detecting a certain/registered beacon in a Region in `didEnterRegion` method. What if I move `RegionBootstrap` to Application class and still use `BeaconConsumer` in my Service? Any binding problems, overlap?

Comment: Actually I should do that even if app is killed. So I do need Service, can't do that in Application class.

Comment: I do not understand why RegionNootstrap cannot be put in an Application class as designed.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I understand that if I use RegionBootstrap in Application class, I won't be able to detect if a beacon is seen in the Region if the app is not running both in foreground and background(killed). I have certain uuid of the beacons so I define in Region. And click the keyfob(beacon) button, notification appears. I think the key here is I try to create Regions and start ranging in onBeaconServiceConnect. Whenever you have time, I may tell you shortly in detail what I do and want to do in chat if possible.